# How to go back to previous screen in tableview?

Tags: iphone

My application is viewbased application in which I have one button. On click of that button I will push to other screen that is table view screen on which what I want when I select any data from row in table view it will get back to previous view automatically instead of selecting the navigation back button generated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```